# Branding Cars on Photoshop / Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, branding, measurement, screen-printing

Any idea on how to Design Printable stuff for different cars. I mean branding a complete car by designing stickers which are than pasted on a car. The main problem is that how can we get the measurements of different things like doors of the car etc...

Answer (score 3):

Do some research on the subject and its not that difficult to find this information. You need to get templates for the wraps either from online or a manufacturer.

> Your design starts with an accurate template of your vehicle — they are available from the manufacturer or [online](http://www.digitalauto.on.ca/) and are essential for creation of your design at the correct size. Most templates come drawn at a scale of 1:20. Change the scale from 1:20 to 1:10 by selecting all and increasing the size by 200%. Now the scale is 1:10, where 1 inch onscreen equals 10 inches in real life. When the files are output, they are scaled at 1000%. It keeps the math simple.

*Source: [10 Tips for Designing Vehicle Wraps in Adobe Illustrator](http://blog.imagesmith.com/2012/01/24/designing-vehicle-wrap-adobe-illustrator/)*

Here's another article on the subject: *[SDGMAG - Vehicle Templates for Wraps](http://sdgmag.com/article/wraps/vehicle-templates-for-wraps)* which indicates this is another useful place to get accurate templates: [digitaldesignware.com](http://www.digitaldesignware.com/).