# Designing for Vehicle Livery

Tags: print-design, template

I've recently taken on a couple of new clients who are now interested in applying their branding to vehicle livery.

I've never really designed in this area before so could do with some advice.

Do I contact the printer that I am going to use to get hold of a template to work to, or is there somewhere that I can get hold of one online? (I have looked, but they all seem to be subscription services).

Any other advice would be much appreciated as this is new territory for me!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kimberly, there are a few previous questions regarding this, have a look at [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/66603/52050) and [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/38078/52050).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with vehicle livery (I assume you are talking about stickers for cars) is that every car is different, therefore, the printing company probably won't have a template. And if they do, they probably won't give it to you as most templates cost money.

You might if you are lucky, you might be able to find in a google "`<CAR MODEL>` vehicle template" for free. However, most of the solutions are paid solutions.

Please note that all artworks should be made in vector, as printing on such a big surfaces makes the pictures look unpleasant (unless in a very high resolution). Also to cut the stickers, the company is using vector data.

Of course, PANTONE colours for the colour matching is the most common one in use.

Comment: Not completely true about the templates. Most places that specialise in vehicle wraps/decals will have most templates and will happily give them to you.

Comment: Weird, when we wanted to design our cars, the company we wanted to make stickers at told us that they can't provide us templates and that we have to use their in-house design department for mock-ups.

Comment: I guess it depends on the company but I've worked with at least 4 or 5 that happily gave me the templates I needed.